# Mapping string values to properties' values in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, function, properties, mapping

i'm a newbie in c# and i have one question

I have a class model like this:

```
 public class SDView
    {
        public int ViewPK { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ConceptOrder { get; set; } 
    }
```

The last property, ConceptOrder contains a string of numbers, each number needs to be mapped to a different property value...

Example:

Being ConceptOrder = "1,2,3,5,4"

```
  public class Item
        {
            public string Warehouse { get; set; } //concept 1
            public string Commodity { get; set; } //concept 2
            public string Variety { get; set; }   //concept 3
            public string Packstyle { get; set; } //concept 4
            public string Size { get; set; }      //concept 5
        }
```

What i need to do is write a method or function that returns (based on above example)

"Warehouse01 BellPepper Green JUMBO 7x1"

ConceptOrder can be any in order, but every number is mapped to a certain Property (1 is always Warehouse... 2 is always Commodity)

Obviously this example is simplified

I can't get my head around this

Any help will be appreciated!

**Edit:**

Exactly what i'm trying to do, is, i have class model with properties:

The property ConceptOrder on the SDView class contains the order in which these properties have to be shown in a string property

So i need a function/method in which i can pass a ConceptOrder ("2, 3, 1, 4, 5") and it returns a formatted string...

```
public class Item
        {
            public string Warehouse { get; set; } //concept 1
            public string Commodity { get; set; } //concept 2
            public string Variety { get; set; }   //concept 3
            public string Packstyle { get; set; } //concept 4
            public string Size { get; set; }      //concept 5

            public string GetProductFromView(string conceptOrder)
           {

           ...

          return "CommodityPropValue VarietyPropValue WarehousePropValue.. etc"
```

}}

Comment: What is some example data for `ConceptOrder` and expected output? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not 100% percent sure what you are trying to do, could you possibly clarify the problem some more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ConceptValue handles each different property and ConceptValues will get the ConceptValue for each value in ConceptOrder and put them in a string with a space between each.

```
public string ConceptValues(string conceptOrder)
{
    var split = conceptOrder.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var nums = split.Select(s => Int32.Parse(s.Trim()));

    return nums.Select(n => ConceptValue(n))
        .Aggregate((acc, s) => string.Format("{0} {1}", acc, s));
}

public string ConceptValue(int concept)
{
    switch (conceptOrder)
    {
        case 1:
            return Warehouse;
        case 2:
            return Commodity;
        // etc...
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Unhandled Concept", "concept");
    }
}
```

Tested using...

```
class Program
{
    private static string str1 { get; set; }
    private static string str2 { get; set; }
    private static string str3 { get; set; }
    private static string ConceptOrder { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        str1 = "string1";
        str2 = "string2";
        str3 = "string3";
        ConceptOrder = "2, 3, 1";
        Console.WriteLine(ConceptValues(ConceptOrder));
        // output: string2 string3 string1
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if i didn't express myself correctly, english is not my native language

What i need to do is return Property values, in the correct order and in just one string, this order is defined by the **ConceptOrder** property

So in the above example, i have to replace "1" with the value of the property **Warehouse**, "2" with the value of property **Commodity** and so one, but everything in just one final string.. like a Description

Comment: Awesome, i'll check it out! Thank you!

Comment: @88Keys FYI, the other answer is basically the same code in concept. Mine is just more verbose with extra precautions (removing empty csv, trimming any whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

So, in class `Item`, you have a method like this

```
public string GetProductFromView(string conceptOrder)
{
    int[] ConceptOrder = conceptOrder.Split(',').Select(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
    string[] Properties = new string[] {Warehouse,Commodity,Variety,Packstyle,Size};
    return string.Join(" ", ConceptOrder.Select(x=>Properties[x]));
}
```

Comment: But, do you understand what and how this is doing it?... oh, and I had forgotten the `.ToArray()` in the first line of the method.

Comment: Did you try it with the `.ToArray()`?  Does it have another problem I am not catching?